# ECMAScript 6 Class this context

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i'm unsure about accessing `this` context in ECMAScript 6 class .

In this example I want to call the method `addItem(..)` of the Class `{this.addItem(data.points);}`

#### How do I bind the this-Conext of the class correctly?

```
class TEST {

  constructor() {}

  testMethod() {

    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
       $.getJSON("test/" + i + ".json", function (data) {
         this.addItem(data.points);
       });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You solve this in exactly the same way as in any other situation. There is nothing specific to `class`es.

Comment: @musa: can you explain why you reopened that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below snippet.

```js
class TEST {

  constructor() {}

  testMethod() {

    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      $.getJSON("test/" + i + ".json", function(data) {
        this.addItem(data.points);
      }.bind(this)); // bind the this of the function you send to $.getJSON to the this of testMethod
    }
  }
}
```

#### Alternative Way:

Use an arrow function, since they inherit the lexical scope of the outer clojure.

```js
class TEST {

  constructor() {}

  testMethod() {

    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      $.getJSON("test/" + i + ".json", data => {
        this.addItem(data.points); // this is the this of testMethod
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)
What way is the more "cleaner" or "more usual" way?

Comment: the arrow function was made for situations when you want the same lexical scope in a callback as in the clojure it was created it, so I would pick that over the bind function. :)

Comment: `this` is not the same as "scope". Don't confuse those two. Scope is not "bound".

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, it's an unfortunate turn of phrase, is inherit better? :)